# Filtro de busqueda con un <select>

Tags: angularjs

Me pidieron añadir un filtro de búsqueda, pero la cosa es que esta realizada con `Angular` la aplicación y se muy poco acerca de eso.

En la `BDD` existe una tabla que se llama `guia` con un campo que se llama `standby` el cual genera un `1` y `0` (si y no).

Logre que trajera los datos para que los ponga en un `div` como puse al final.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo hacer el filtro de búsqueda cuando en el `div` se active con un `select`?

```
<select class="form-control" name="standby">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Guías en standby</option>
    <option value="">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">Si</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

Y al presionar este botón, busque dependiendo de las opciones (porque son varios filtros).

`<button ng-click="buscar()" class="btn blue">Buscar</button>`

Aquí muestra el resultado, dependiendo de un `checkbox` que tengo en otro lugar, si esta checkeado los muestra `guia en standby` y si le quitas el check se quita el `div`.

```
<div ng-if="guia.standby==1">
    <div class="label label-default label-sm">Guía en standby</div>
</div>
```

[image: Referencia]

Al presionar `Si` en el `select`, muestre solo el que dice guía en `standby`.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega a tu select la etiqueta `ng-model="guia.standby"` por ejemplo.

En tu controlador, dentro de la funcion `buscar()` puedes obtener el valor que toma el `<select>` dependiendo de la seleccion del usuario... por ejemplo

```
$scope.buscar = function () {
    console.log($scope.guia.standby); //Puede imprimir "" ==> Todas, "1" ==> Si, "0" ==> No
}
```

Respecto a tu `<div>` deberia ser asi el `ng-if` asi podras mostrar el `<label>` que quieres.

```
<div ng-if="guia.standby == '1'">
    <div class="label label-default label-sm">Guía en standby</div>  
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-model="guia.standby">
    <option value="">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">Si</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
  </select>
  
  <div ng-if="guia.standby == '1'">
    <p>Guía en standby</p>
  </div>
</div>
```